# Issue with loading sessionFactory

Tags: spring, hibernate

I have created a spring-hibernate application which executes perfectly when executed through the command prompt.

I load the application context as follows

```
ApplicationContext appContext = 
          new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("config/BeanLocations.xml");
```

Now I am trying to use the same application in a jersey web application to retrieve data from the database. However I get the following error.

> ```
> exception
> ```
>
> javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
>     com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:420)
>     com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:537)
>     com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:699)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728) root
>   cause
>
> java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
>     com.example.HelloWorldService.getMsg(HelloWorldService.java:25)
>     sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>     sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>     sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>     java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
>     com.sun.jersey.spi.container.JavaMethodInvokerFactory$1.invoke(JavaMethodInvokerFactory.java:60)
>     com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$TypeOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:185)
>     com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75)
>     com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:288)
>     com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
>     com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108)
>     com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
>     com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84)
>     com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1469)
>     com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1400)
>     com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1349)
>     com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1339)
>     com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:416)
>     com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:537)
>     com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:699)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728) root
>   cause
>
> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path
>   resource [database/Hibernate.xml]: Invocation of init method failed;
>   nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder
>     org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1338)
>     org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:473)
>     org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory$1.run(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:409)
>     java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>     org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:380)
>     org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:264)
>     org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
>     org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:261)
>     org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:185)
>     org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:164)
>     org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:423)
>     org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:728)
>     org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:380)
>     org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
>     org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
>     com.forum.util.ModelGenerator.(ModelGenerator.java:12)
>     com.example.HelloWorldService.getMsg(HelloWorldService.java:25)
>     sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>     sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>     sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>     java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
>     com.sun.jersey.spi.container.JavaMethodInvokerFactory$1.invoke(JavaMethodInvokerFactory.java:60)
>     com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$TypeOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:185)
>     com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75)
>     com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:288)
>     com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
>     com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108)
>     com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
>     com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84)
>     com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1469)
>     com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1400)
>     com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1349)
>     com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1339)
>     com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:416)
>     com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:537)
>     com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:699)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728) root
>   cause
>
> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder
>     org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.(LoggerFactory.java:60)
>     org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.Version.(Version.java:12)
>     org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.(AnnotationConfiguration.java:78)
>     sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>     sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
>     sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
>     java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
>     org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:100)
>     org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:78)
>     org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean.newConfiguration(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:772)
>     org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:517)
>     org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.AbstractSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractSessionFactoryBean.java:211)
>     org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1369)
>     org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1335)
>     org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:473)
>     org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory$1.run(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:409)
>     java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>     org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:380)
>     org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:264)
>     org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
>     org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:261)
>     org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:185)
>     org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:164)
>     org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:423)
>     org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:728)
>     org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:380)
>     org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
>     org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
>     com.forum.util.ModelGenerator.(ModelGenerator.java:12)
>     com.example.HelloWorldService.getMsg(HelloWorldService.java:25)
>     sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>     sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>     sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>     java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
>     com.sun.jersey.spi.container.JavaMethodInvokerFactory$1.invoke(JavaMethodInvokerFactory.java:60)
>     com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$TypeOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:185)
>     com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75)
>     com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:288)
>     com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
>     com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108)
>     com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
>     com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84)
>     com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1469)
>     com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1400)
>     com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1349)
>     com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1339)
>     com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:416)
>     com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:537)
>     com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:699)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728) root
>   cause
>
> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder
>     org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1714)
>     org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559)
>     org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.(LoggerFactory.java:60)
>     org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.Version.(Version.java:12)
>     org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.(AnnotationConfiguration.java:78)
>     sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>     sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
>     sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
>     java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
>     org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:100)
>     org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:78)
>     org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean.newConfiguration(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:772)
>     org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:517)
>     org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.AbstractSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractSessionFactoryBean.java:211)
>     org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1369)
>     org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1335)
>     org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:473)
>     org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory$1.run(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:409)
>     java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>     org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:380)
>     org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:264)
>     org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
>     org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:261)
>     org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:185)
>     org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:164)
>     org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:423)
>     org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:728)
>     org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:380)
>     org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
>     org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
>     com.forum.util.ModelGenerator.(ModelGenerator.java:12)
>     com.example.HelloWorldService.getMsg(HelloWorldService.java:25)
>     sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>     sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>     sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>     java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
>     com.sun.jersey.spi.container.JavaMethodInvokerFactory$1.invoke(JavaMethodInvokerFactory.java:60)
>     com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$TypeOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:185)
>     com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75)
>     com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:288)
>     com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
>     com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108)
>     com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
>     com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84)
>     com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1469)
>     com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1400)
>     com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1349)
>     com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1339)
>     com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:416)
>     com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:537)
>     com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:699)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)

As I am new to Spring and Hibernate, please let me know if I can use this simple Java standalone application with a web application. Or what are the changes I should make?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your application doesn't have `slf4j` in the `classpath`.

Comment: Thank you. That solved the issue. Added this fix [link](http://www.mkyong.com/wicket/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-org-slf4j-impl-staticloggerbinder/)